# Поменять вывод в консоль на вывод в файл

Tags: c++, логирование

Есть функция вывода поддерживаемых процессором инструкций в консоль. Помогите переделать чтобы сохранялось в файлик.

```
auto& outstream = std::cout;  

auto support_message = [&outstream](std::string isa_feature, bool is_supported) {  
    outstream << isa_feature << (is_supported ? " supported" : " not supported") << std::endl;  
};
```

Comment: Инициализируйте `outstream` не как `cout`, а как открытый `ofstream`... Еще лучше - передавайте ссылку на `ostream`, куда писать, как параметр.

Comment: Не шарю я в с++. Пробовал вот так 
auto& outstream = ofstream f("Test.txt"); Не вышло.

Comment: @ModNick: Т.е. вы не знакомы даже с базовым синтаксисом языка?

Comment: Нет) Потому и попросил тут помощи.

Answer (score 3):

```
auto support_message = [](std::ostream& out, std::string isa_feature, bool is_supported) {  
    return out << isa_feature
               << (is_supported ? " supported" : " not supported") << std::endl;  
};
```

Ну, а потом

```
ofstream log("Logfile",ios::ate);

support_message(cout,"feature",true);
support_message(log,"feature",true);
```

Примерно так.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал вот так. Работает)

```
ofstream log("Logfile.txt");

auto support_message = [&log](std::string isa_feature, bool is_supported) {   log << isa_feature << (is_supported ? " supported" : " not supported") << std::endl;  };
```

Comment: Этот вариант плох использованием глобальной переменной. Ваш `support_message` в результате работает только с одним потоком, в то время как мог бы работать с **любым**.